# Unique combinations of (permuted) list

Tags: python, pandas, permutation

Consider the following list:

`data["categories"].value_counts()` 
I get

```
c          110
b           81
d           80
a           70
c,b         43
          ... 
d,a,b,c      2
a,b,c,d      2
a,b,d        1
a,c,d,b      1
d,c,a,b      1
Name: categories, Length: 62, dtype: int64
```

I want to count the unique instance of each combination but due to different ordering, it counts `a,b,c` versus `c,b,a` as two separate elements where as I want to count count them as the same.

so I attempted to first list them first them sort them

```
list = data["categories"]
L = []
# getting length of list
length = len(list)

for i in range(len(data["categories"])):
    L.append(sorted(list[i]))

for j in range(len(L)):
    M.append(L[i].remove(','))
```

The problem with this archaic method is that it leaves the ',' from the list and those then need to be manually removed.

and then manually remove the ','

`[',', 'a', 'd']` --> `['a','d']`

Is there a more intelligent way of doing this?

Comment: So when you say `a,b,c`, do you mean the string `'a,b,c'` rather than the list `[a,b,c]`? Also, you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name, as it is a preset variable type. That's why it's orange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

1. Split each of the string values in index by `,` and then use set to re-order them.
2. Join them back with `,` and overwrite the original index
3. Finally, use `pd.Series.groupby` over `level=0` to take sum of counts

```
s = data["categories"].value_counts()

#d,a,b,c    2
#a,b,c,d    2
#a,b,d      1
#a,c,d,b    1
#d,c,a,b    1
#Name: count, dtype: int64

s.index = [','.join(sorted(set(i.split(',')))) for i in df1.index]
s.groupby(level=0).sum()
```

```
a,b,c,d    6
a,b,d      1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you so much Akshay, this is almost exactly what I want ... except it still lists `a,d` and `d,a` separately where they should be counted the same. I believe I need to add sorting between split and join.

Comment: Updated my answer. Do check if this works for you now. Also, if it helped, then do mark the answer  and do upvote it if it’s well written to your liking. This encourages me to help solve your future questions :)